# Solve $y'-2y=3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $y'-2y=3$

I found an integration factor $\mu=e^{-2x}$.

Then $$e^{-2x}y'-2e^{-2x}y=3e^{-2x} \implies \int(e^{-2x}y)'=\int3e^{-2x}dx\implies e^{-2x}y=-1.5e^{-2x} \implies y=-1.5$$

The correct answer is $e^{2x}-\frac{3}{2}$

Where am I wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: @Moo It's correct ,it is a Separable Equation , but why can't I solve it finding an integration factor?

Comment: $e^{-2x}y=-1.5e^{-2x}+c\implies y=-1.5+Ce^{2x}$

Comment: You forgot the integration constant $C$.

Comment: Were you given an initial condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $e^{-2x}y=-1.5e^{-2x}+C$ so $y=ce^{2x}-\frac{3}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int{\left(e^{-2x}y\right)'dx} = \int{3e^{-2x}dx} \Leftrightarrow \\
& e^{-2x}y = 3\left(-\frac{1}2\right)e^{-2x}+C \Rightarrow \\
& y = Ce^{2x}-\frac{3}{2}
\end{aligned} 
$$